# Typescript: Generic class where unbound type depends on another generic

Tags: typescript

I have some classes

```js
class EventBase<T> {
  constructor(readonly target: T) {}
}

class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

I want to have event-specific handler for each event type.
What currently works is:

```js
class EventHandler<T extends A, E extends Event<T>> {
   public doSomething(): T {...}
   public doSomethingElse(): {...}
}
```

With this, I can now have a specific mouse event:

```js
class MouseClickEvent extends Event<B> {
   constructor(target: B) {
      super(target);
   }
}
```

And initialise a mouse event handler:

```js
const mouseClickHandler = new EventHandler<B, MouseClickEvent>();
```

Now the thing that bugs me:

**Why specify `B` in the constructor of `EventHandler` when it should already be known that `T=B` from `E=MouseClickEvent extends Event<B>`.
Can I somehow infer `T` from `E` and still use `T` in `EventHandler`?**

Removing the explicit deceleration of `T` from `EventHandler` (i.e. `class EventHandler<E extends Event<T>>`) yields `Cannot find name 'T'.`

Is it possible to have a generic type which extends a type of another generic type without having to mention it explicitly during type deceleration or when calling the constructor?

Edit: I initially left out the fact that `T` also has a constraint.
`T extends A` for some class A. This makes it even more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround I found was using `infer`:

I define a type

```js
type TargetType<E extends EventBase<unknown>> = E extends EventBase<infer T> ? T : never;
```

and change `EventHandler` such that

```js
class EventHandler<E extends Event<T>, T=TargetType<E>> {
   public doSomething(): T {...}
   public doSomethingElse(): E {...}
}
```

Edit: This doesn't seem to work if `T` has a further constraint `T extends A`.